# insertOrderedList command in contenteditable div passes styles and inserts <font> tag to list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, contenteditable

I have an editor using contenteditable div just like SO editor. I have orderedlist and unorderedlist feature and I execute commands like `document.execCommand('insertOrderedList');`
The problem when I execute this command:

I expect this:

```
<p><ol><li>dfsdfsdfsdf</li></ol></p>
```

But this happens:

```
<p><ol><li><font face="verdana, sans-serif"><span style="font-size: 12px; line-height: normal;">dfsdfsdfsdf</span></font></li></ol></p>
```

It inserts font and span tags. I wonder it is about css reset file; but I couldn't find the source of problem.